# What does this gcc command mean?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

```
gcc test.c 2> error-msg
```

Could anyone explain each part of this command, like `2>` `error-msg`?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: `error -msg` or `error-msg`

Comment: `gcc test.c 2> error -msg` is the same as `gcc test.c -msg 2> error`, which means your shell executes `gcc test.c -msg` and redirects its standard error output to file called `error`. And the `error` file will likely contain " error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msg’"

Comment: @nsilent22 could you post this as an answer?

Comment: From a class assignment, it can work but I do not know the exact meaning.

Comment: @jacob: Here you are.

Comment: Why does someone gave me a down vote, I do not think it is a normal gcc command, since I did not find any answer in google! I only have 16 reputations! !!

Comment: `2> error-msg` has nothing to do with `gcc`, it's basic shell syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the command to be `gcc test.c 2> error-msg`. `2>` means redirect the error stream of the command `gcc test.c` to the file named `error-msg` (standard messages will be printed on screen as usual).

If it is really `gcc test.c 2> error -msg` then the executed command will be `gcc test.c -msg` and the error stream redirected to the file `error`. It is not very common to redirect in the middle of a command line.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know the purpose of using `-msg`

Comment: You are true, I made a mistake in my question, it is `error-msg`

Comment: There is NO (useful) purpose for `-msg`.  All it gets you is a file with `cc1: error: invalid option \`sg'` or `cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-msg"` in it (depending on the version of your gcc).

Comment: *not very common*, but it [even works on Windows](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yr1o-UYjjIIJ:stackoverflow.com/a/7225821#7225821)... (link to Google cache because the comment regarding the Unix heritage has since been removed)

Answer (score 2):

`gcc test.c 2> error -msg` is the same as `gcc test.c -msg 2> error`, which means your shell executes `gcc test.c -msg` and redirects its standard error output to file called `error`. And the `error` file will likely contain " error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msg’"

Comment: Thanks, but what is `-msg ` for?

Comment: @brickmanjim: Well, I have no idea. My gcc has no such option. Maybe space between error and -msg is just a typo, and this should be just redirection to error-msg file?